# Why doesn't validate.js work with two ID on the element and how do I fix it?

Tags: jquery, html

http://emopreview.co.uk/mini/MINI-ISSD-Holding-Pages/uk-forces-form.html

Hi Guys,

I'm trying to make validation work on all select tags that I have put dropkick.js on so I can style those bad boys up. But this requires two ID names "select" and "required". When I take the select ID off it works. I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this and if so what they have done to fix the issue? Below is my html and Jquery calling to the script.

Jquery

```
$("#emf-form").validate();
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {

$('html').removeClass('dk_fouc');
$('.select').addClass('ios');

}else{
// Add dropkick selectbox styling to property search form */
$('.select').dropkick();
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="element_4" name="element_4" class="required select">
  <option value=""selected="selected">Please select</option>
  <option value="Diplomatic">Diplomatic</option>
  <option value="British Forces Germany">British Forces Germany</option>
  <option value="Export & LHD">Export &amp; LHD</option>
</select>
```

There is also a link to show what I have done.

Thanks

Comment: Those are classes not IDs, right?

Comment: refer to that element as $(".required.select") and then try your code. It should do the trick for you.

Comment: jesus.. yeah i meant classes.. long morning.. Alright thanks will give it ago

Comment: Sorry I don't understand waht you mean changing the element to "$(".required.select")" do you mean in the script? So change #emf-form to what you have suggested?